# Can't call an intent from FragmentActivity

Tags: android, button, android-intent, android-activity

I have my login screen, and on one of the pages of the ViewPager there is a Login button. I am trying to make this button go straight to the main activity because I don't have all of the server side sorted out yet. When I do that though, I get this error:

```
01-21 14:51:33.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2256): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-21 14:51:33.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2256): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fbla.sap/com.fbla.sap.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-21 14:51:33.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2256):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2304)
01-21 14:51:33.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2256):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
01-21 14:51:33.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2256):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
01-21 14:51:33.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2256):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
01-21 14:51:33.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2256):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-21 14:51:33.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2256):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-21 14:51:33.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2256):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5450)
01-21 14:51:33.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2256):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-21 14:51:33.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2256):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-21 14:51:33.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2256):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
01-21 14:51:33.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2256):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
01-21 14:51:33.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2256):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-21 14:51:33.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2256): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-21 14:51:33.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2256):     at com.fbla.sap.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:23)
01-21 14:51:33.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2256):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5369)
01-21 14:51:33.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2256):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
01-21 14:51:33.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2256):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
01-21 14:51:33.499: E/AndroidRuntime(2256):     ... 11 more
```

Here is my source code for LoginActivity.java:

```
package com.fbla.sap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class LoginActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        Button loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, InterfaceActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure res/layout/activity_login.xml contains <Button android:id="@+id/loginBtn" ... />?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Button loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
```

loginBtn is probably null.

Comment: That might be it. I have the button in one of my fragments, and not in the view created by this fragment. Any options on how to fix this?

Comment: Since it's in your fragment, you should put this clicklistener part inside your fragment, and when your fragment is in foreground and be clicked, it'll open MainActivity.

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you!